# Laravel HTML tags doesn't insert in online server

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I'm using Laravel 7 with TinyMCE. **On my localhost it's working fine** - no issues at all. But when try on online server (cpanel shared hosting) its not working, some HTML tag not working - cannot insert to database (nothing happen).

This example is working - can insert to database:

`<p><a href="http://url/file.pdf">yeye</a></p>`

This example not working - can't insert to database(nothing happen):

`<p><span style="color: blue;">blue</span></p>`

Another not working example:

`<p><video controls="controls" width="300" height="150"> <source src="http://url/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video></p>`

Here is my Laravel controller:

```
        $this -> validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'details'=>'required',
            'status'=>'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $slug = str_slug($input['title'],'-');
        $input['slug'] = $slug;

        $data = Page::create($input);
        $data->save();

        Session::flash('success', trans('flash.AddedSuccessfully'));
        return redirect('page');
```

Comment: Why you added `$data->save();` delete that line

Comment: Removed it, still facing same problem

Comment: try changing your database column collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Thanks but it's already utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the size of the content column in the database. This means change the type from varchar to text.